# How to get html code from Wordpress post content?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to wrap decode all html tags from a post content in Wordpress.

**like**

```
&lt;iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FRocketsAreCool%2Fvideos%2F1032994553496742%2F&amp;show_text=0&amp;width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"&gt;
```

When I try this code:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('name'=>'example_topic'));
$post = $query->posts;
$text = htmlspecialchars_decode($post->content);
```

It works, but not closing the html tag because the tag was not originally closed in the encoded tags, so every thing comes after not showing in browser.